# Достать файл из директории, названной по-русски

Tags: python, sqlite, кодировка

Здравствуйте!

Хочу достать файл из директории, названной по-русски. Например, директория:

> C:\User\Имя_пользователя\1234

Тогда я пишу:

```
path = 'C:\Users\\' + getpass.getuser() + '\1234' 
conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если `unicode(getpass.getuser())`? А если экранировать все слэши?

Comment: @Etki, C Юникодом помогло! Спасибо большое! :)

Answer (score 0):

Перед `getpass.`   попробуй `/r`.